# Adwords Keyword Tool API

Tags: google-adwords

Is there an API to access the results returned by the Keyword Tool in Google Adwords?

Also, is there a site that provides an API to verify if a domain is taken?

Comment: this is two different questions..

Comment: They are related thought. When I have the list of domains that match the keywords I want to automatically check which ones are available and produce, for example, an Excel files with the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Adwords API](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/) lets you access the Adwords Keyword Tool.

For domain name availability checks, there is a now closed question on Stack Overflow:
[Finding if domain name is already registered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019862)

Let me know if you still miss something.

Comment: I looked at the API and I can't find in the documentation anything about keywords. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Igratian have a look here: http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/TargetingIdeaService.html  and the examples... http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#Fu0vUbQ37f4/trunk/examples/v201008/GetRelatedKeywords.php&q=google-api-adwords%20Tags:.*TargetingIdeaService%20v201008&sa=N&ct=rx&cd=1